# Strange behaviour of static shared_ptr

Tags: c++, static, shared-ptr

So I have no idea what really is going on, but somehow it is related to accessing a static shared_ptr. I'm using the `spdlog` library. In my header file I have the following:

```
/** This is the main logger sink used by Metadiff */
        static const std::shared_ptr<spdlog::sinks::dist_sink_st> md_sink(new spdlog::sinks::dist_sink_st());

        /** Creates a new logger linked to md_sink */
        std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger(std::string name);
//    {
//            std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> ptr = spdlog::get(name);
//            if (not ptr) {
//                ptr = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>(name, md_sink);
//                spdlog::register_logger(ptr);
//                ptr->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
//                ptr->set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S][%l][%n] %v");
//            }
//            return ptr;
//        }
```

In the corresponding cpp file:

```
std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger(std::string name)  {
            std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> ptr = spdlog::get(name);
            if (not ptr) {
                ptr = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>(name, md::utils::md_sink);
                spdlog::register_logger(ptr);
                ptr->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
                ptr->set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S][%l][%n] %v");
            }
            return ptr;
        }
```

Now when I try to run my code this for some reason does not work and I don't understand why (e.g. when I try to log a message I don't get anything). If I remove the implementation from the cpp file and put it in the header file (and make it inline) it magically works.

Please someone explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why use the `static` keyword?  This means there will be a distinct `md_sink` for every source file that includes your header.

Comment: Is that what static implies when it is in a namespace?

Comment: If I remove the static it complains about multiple definition. My guess is I actually need to define it inside a function, is that correct?

Comment: @aschepler it will be the same with or without `static`, as `const` objects default to internal linkage

Comment: @Belov The obvious solution is to move the `md_sink` definition to the same source file as the body of `logger()`

Comment: Yes I think I see what is the solution, as I needed it in other functions I moved it to a separate function log_sink(). Anyway if any of you wants to write just a bit on why static does not matter (with or without the const still did not work) I'm happy to accept an answer.